# Formatting console output when running multiple Unit Tests in vstest.console.exe

Tags: c#, unit-testing, formatting, vstest, vstest.console.exe

**Situation**
 
I'm using vstest.console.exe to run some unit test projects at once. Also I am interested in the console output since I cannot use I/O operations to log results to .trx file. I am also limited to one instance of vstest.console.exe. So I want to run UnitTests1.dll, UnitTests2.dll etc. all at once. I'm achieving this in following way `vstest.console.exe UnitTests1.dll UnitTests2.dll`. This works just fine as tests get executed and I get my console output.

**Problem**
The problem I run into is the formatting of the output. It looks something like this [default output from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E40HS.png). The issue is that all the unit test projects are bundled together as if I'm running a single unit tests project.

**Goal**
I want to have the output from each Unit Test project on its own separate line as it were, something like this
`UnitTests1: Total tests: 3. Passed: 2. Failed: 1. Skipped 0.`
`UnitTests2: Total tests: 3. Passed: 3. Failed: 0. Skipped 0.`

In other words, is it even possible to format* console output in vstest.console.exe? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj155796.aspx) vstest.console.exe doesn't support formatting, but it has logger option, where You can specify what You want to do with output. There is created logger on [GitHub](https://github.com/markvincze/MsTestTrxLogger).

You can force the vstest.console.exe to make an xml formatted file with result, then parse the results with Your app (as You require) -> basically create wrapper around.